# What does "the mountains gave way" mean?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context

The full paragraph I'm reading is this:

> Pascal’s parents had moved to Bel Air at a time when the neighborhood was inhabited mostly by peasants, living there temporarily so that their children could finish primary school. But as the trees in the provinces vanished into charcoal and **the mountains gave way**, washing the country’s topsoil into the sea, they, like the others, stayed and raised their two sons and at least a thousand pigeons, which, over the years, they sold both alive and dead.

from: https://www.newyorker.com/magazine/2008/11/24/ghosts-fiction-edwidge-danticat

The most relevant definition I could get from [the Cambridge dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/give-way) is

> to break, especially when under pressure from strong forces

but how can a bunch of mountains break? I have no idea.

Comment: It seems like something is missing: certainly, the mountains can't be "washing the country's topsoil into the sea", so probably there was something in there that was accidentally deleted. (You could say "the mountains gave way to flatter ground" or "The mountains gave way over millions of years" but neither fits here.)

Comment: Perhaps it rains a lot in Bel Air and the erosion of the mountains washed the topsoil into the sea. This would have been exacerbated by the fires which previously turned the trees to charcoal.

Comment: @mdewey Hmm, I can go with that. But as StuartF stated seems like something is missing there (or the text is not correctly written).

Comment: It's the New Yorker. You should not expect well-written prose from this source. The author was trying to say that heavy periods of rain washed away the topsoil; in a poetic sense, the mountains "gave way" that is, surrendered or gave up, letting go of their topsoil.

Comment: Why should you not expect well-written prose?  This is from a professional writer and is edited and published.  While you should not expect well-written prose in tweets or internet forums, this is exactly the sort of source that you should expect to be well written.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The author is "[waxing lyrical](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/to-wax-lyrical)".  Reading around the context, it seems to be saying that the fertile land in the mountains was broken and washed away.

This made the farms in the provinces less productive, so former peasants chose to stay in the slums and shantytowns near the cities.

For context, Wikipedia has an article about the loss of fertile land in Haiti